# Prove that $e^\frac{x+y}{2} < \frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^y)$ for $x\neq y$

Tags: inequality

Should I use the taylor series expansion of the exponential function?

Comment: you can  Use Jenson inequality

Comment: In beginning calculus, this is a consequence of the fact that the function $e^x$ has positive second derivative, is "concave up."

Comment: @math110 Jensen's inequality*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By AM-GM,

$$a=e^x,\space b=e^y$$
$$\sqrt{ab}\le \frac{a+b}2$$
$$e^{\frac{x+y}2}\le \frac{e^x+e^y}2$$
Equality happens when $x=y$, so for $x\ne y$ only $<$ will hold.

Comment: Would be even more easy be seen with $u=e^\frac x{2},\;\;v=e^\frac y{2}$

Answer (score 1):

In general if $f''>0$ and $x>y$ then there exist $a\in ([x+y]/2,x)$ and $b\in (y,[x+y]/2)$ and $c\in (a.b)$ such that $$[f(x)+f(y)]/2 -f([x+y]/2)=$$ $$[f(x)-f([x+y]/2)]/2-[f([x+y]/2)-f(y)]/2=$$ $$=[(x-y)f'(a)]/4-[(x-y)f'(b)]/4=(x-y)^2f''(c)/4>0.$$

Comment: More generally if $f''>0$ and $r\in (0,1)$ and $x\ne y$ then $r f(x)+(1-r)f(y)>f(r x+(1-r)y)$.